Semantic-release plugin sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't
url: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
status: 502
RequestError [HttpError]: Unknown error: {"data":null,"errors":[{"message":"Something went wrong while executing your query. This may be the result of a timeout, or it could be a GitHub bug. Please include `**********` when reporting this issue."}]}

The semantic-release execution failed but tag was created for it.
Sometimes the execution is successful.
